# Is it a security threat to have food or drink next to computers

Tags: physical

I have never worked in big organization and I wonder if any of them considers food or drinks a security threat. More than one movie showed the scenario of an operator who accidentally spills tea on the control panel and cause the train to get out of control or some missiles to get launched.

Comment: Having idiots in the launch control center is a much graver threat to security.

Comment: Burritos tend to cause backdoor security breaches more often than not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you've been watching too many movies.

Food and drink are not security threats. That being said, it's not really appropriate to be leaving cups of coffee or bottles of water on top of critical systems, for obvious reasons.

Comment: To be fair, having the user use a critical system as an everyday device is most certainly a security flaw.

Comment: It does mean having liquid and other potentially harmful substances within close proximity to electronic equipment which could result in data loss or service outage. It's a reasonable line item in your risk analysis threat sheet.

Comment: @ScottPack agreed, not a 'security' threat, but a risk often covered under Security due to risks to Availability.